# What is a Fishbone Diagram?

Tags: project-management

Why are "cause and effect" diagrams also called  "fishbone diagrams" ?

What is a Fishbone Diagram?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 11):

A [Fishbone diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishbone_diagram) is also known as a Ishikawa diagram.  It is so named because it looks like a fish's backbone.

[image: Fishbone Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Because an Ishikawa / cause-and-effect diagram can be plotted in a shape resembling a fishbone.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishikawa_diagram

Comment: +1 it took me 44 seconds to get the wiki link =>

Answer (score 1):

because they resemble fish bones like in a whole fish.

See this for more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishikawa_diagram

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't look like a ham bone.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101548/why-is-the-called-a-caret

Answer (score 1):

Ishikawa diagrams are useful in determining the breadth (or cause density) of a problem. Using a technique such as the "5 Whys" is useful for determining a problem's depth.  Understanding both the depth and the breadth of a problem is fundamental in root cause analysis.

Answer (score -1):

Because they look like a fishes skeleton / bones.

Use Why Tree or similar. Ishikawa and 5 Why are a pretty good introduction to RCA but are limited and often miss or overlook true root causes.